# Ctrl+Alt registering as AltGr for US International Alternate, any way to disable?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I am using the US International Alternate keyboard layout on Windows. Google Docs has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to enter a comment, but with this keyboard layout that registers as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, which produces `µ`. Is there any way to prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> from registering as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>?

Comment: This *is not a duplicate*, @slhck, as you can see in that question, the answers are how to avoid AltGr, not *how to avoid Alt+Ctrl becoming AltGr, without disabling AltGr.

Comment: @Etoy I guess the question was closed as a duplicate because of the original problem being about Google Docs and keyboard shortcuts with US International layouts. The OP then asks how to achieve a possible solution they thought of, which you've included in the other post, as far as I can tell. Don't think it's required to reopen this, but if you think it really should, and that there should be an answer that doesn't fit the other question, the best would be to go to [meta] and ask for it – I can't reopen it as I'm not a moderator anymore.

Comment: the corect duplicate should be [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)