# Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Many applications like Google Docs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for heading 2, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for comments etc. However, in case of international keyboards' layouts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, so many of these shortcuts produce special characters instead, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> = @. Therefore these shortcuts can not be used.

Is there a way to disable this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> = <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, such that <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> = @ but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> can be used as a shortcut?

---

There has been some earlier post with answers related to this problem:

- [Why don't the Google Docs CTRL + ALT shortcuts work?](https://superuser.com/questions/217082/why-dont-the-google-docs-ctrl-alt-shortcuts-work)
- [Ctrl+Alt registering as AltGr for US International Alternate, any way to disable?](https://superuser.com/questions/313369/ctrlalt-registering-as-altgr-for-us-international-alternate-any-way-to-disable)

Both solutions are however related to unassign the special character completely. These solutions do not disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> binding. This means, that in order to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> as a shortcut, I am not able to write @ at all, which is naturally not an option.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have researched further and looked at the other answers. It seems like the short answer is: *No! Windows treats* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> *and* <kbd>AltGr</kbd> *identically*.

**But** there is a hack. Essentially we do not let Windows handle <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key bindings and instead use a third party tool that knows the difference. We do this manually for every singe key.

This hack does not work with "[dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_keys)" such as <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>.

.

**Part 1: Let AutoHotKey convert** <kbd>AltGr</kbd>**+**<kbd>Some Key</kbd> **to symbols**
[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can distinguish between <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. It can also transform keystrokes like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>**+**<kbd>2</kbd> to a single symbol `@`, *before* Windows applies its keyboard layout.

1. [Download](http://l.autohotkey.net/AutoHotkey_L_Install.exe) and install AutoHotKey
2. Create a new script, i.e., a plain text file with the extension `.ahk`
3. For each character you want to write with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>BUTTON</kbd>=CHAR, create a line like this:
   `<^>!BUTTON::SendInput {raw}CHAR`
   Example: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>=@ becomes `<^>!2::SendInput {raw}@`
4. Save the script

If you want to test your script, you can create some arbitrary mapping like `<^>!t::SendInput {raw}tttt`. Double click the script to apply it and test if <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> produces four t's when you type.

.

**Part 2: Get windows out of the way:**

We want to remove all assignments of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Any Key</kbd> on they keyboard, so Windows never convert them into characters.

First we need to create a new keyboard layout.

1. Download [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339). It is a simple tool that lets you modify your keyboard layout. ([Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22339))
2. Open to tool and `File -> Load Existing Keyboard` and choose your keyboard layout.
3. Select `File -> Save source as` and give it a new name.
4. Tick the `Alt+Ctrl (AltGr)`.
   You might want to select `File -> Save as Image` to make a note of the original assignments.
5. Remove all assigned keys, by clicking them, deleting the symbol, and click `OK`
   **Do not clear** any dead keys! (The grey ones). Check for all modifiers i.e. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or none!
6. Go to `Projet -> Propertie` and give it a decent name and description.
7. Save it: `File -> Save Source File` so you can edit it later
8. Export setup: `Project -> Build DLL and Setup Package`

Then we need to apply this new keyboard layout.

1. Find the exported setup files in you Documents folder, and double click `setup.exe`. This will install your new keyboard layout.
2. Open the input setting by going to `Control Pannel -> Change keyboards and other input methods -> Change keybords`
3. Click `Add` select you own keyboard and make it default.
   Come back here and remove the standard keyboard, once your confident everything works well.

.

**Part 3: Let AutoHotKey take over:**
Now lets put everything into action:

1. Make sure your new keyboard is selected in the language task bar, and AutoHotKey is not running minimized in the notification tray.
2. Try to type your special characters. This should not work.
3. Double click on you AutoHotKey script. So it launches
4. Try to type special characters again. This should now work with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> only.
5. To make sure the script is loaded when Windows starts, create a short-cut to it in the `Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder

That's it! (ツ) You can share the keyboard layout setup files and the `.ahk` script, with other computers to skip most of the steps.

---

**Other resources:**
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/replace-default-windows-keyboard-shortcut-behavior/0c5ff2a4-6bea-49a9-88bc-669049a1e107 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/alt-gr-keys-HP005259063.aspx 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040329-00/?p=40003 
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/61625-how-to-avoid-that-ctrl-alt-altgr/

Comment: Another valuable resource is Michael Kaplan's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/).

Comment: removing AltGr+Key assignments will only work if your language doesn't require the use of AltGr

Comment: I got this to kind of work. Problem is the Keyboard Layout Creator is buggy. Be prepared to install and uninstall layouts multiple times. Sometimes uninstalls don't work the first time. The description doesn't update properly, which you can fix in the registry `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\`, the DLLs can be found in `System32`. I give up at making this work 100% at this point

Comment: Seems like Windows needs to reboot to do some keyboard related things, like reflect updated descriptions and removing deleted keyboards from the control panel. This was way more of a pain in the ass then I had hoped. Seems to work okay now though. Had to create explicit capitalization commands in AutoHotKey, ie both `<^>!q::SendInput {raw}ä` and `<+<^>!q::SendInput {raw}Ä`

Comment: What if I want the opposite? I want AltGr characters to work normally, but I don't want the shortcuts bound to Alt+Ctrl to steal and disable my special characters available with AltGr. In Polish keyboard, AltGr+s gives "ś" but if a programs maps Ctrl+Alt+s, then I can no longer type "ś". Is it fixable? I mean to Ctrl+Alt+s to activate a shortcut, but AlgGr+s type "ś"?

Comment: AutoHotKey actually CANNOT distinguish between AltGr and Ctrl+Alt. The modifier combination `<^>!` in your instructions means Left Ctrl and Right Alt specifically. If you press those two keys instead of just AltGr, your AutoHotKey will trigger as well.

Comment: @Harry, please see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762911/22750) below (closer to its end).

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the numeric keyboard can be used instead of regular number keys to activate Google Docs shortcuts. Using AHK this works also on laptops without numeric keys. For example,

```
<^<!2::SendInput ^!{Numpad2}
```

will activate header 2 without printing @. No need to use MSKLC.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to have a look at [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Its a free Tool and you can also change shortcut-effects very easy. Have a look at the [Hotkey-Documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) at their website. It is really easy to understand and really easy to use. You can remap every key/shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your current Windows keyboard layout your AltGr key will translate either to Right Alt + Left Control (e.g. on International US, Russian or Polish Pro layouts), or just to Right Alt (e.g. on English US layout). And as far as I know there is no way on Windows to have AltGr on the international layouts to be distinguished from Right Alt + Left Control simultaneous combination.

But, depending on your needs, you can workaround this with the help of [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

If you use the international layout just to be able to enter a couple of characters like diacritics, then you can switch to the corresponding non-international layout, which does not treat AltGr as Right Alt + Left Control, like English US layout, and just add the AutoHotKey script for the special characters you need. E.g.

```
>!2::SendInput "{Text}²"
```

will enter ² when you press Right Alt + 2 on English US layout. The Ctrl+Alt+2 combination will not be affected and will be free for other usage.

If you still need to use your international layout, then you'll need to change the AutoHotKey script above to

```
<^>!2::SendInput "{Text}²"
^!2::SendInput "^!2"
```

which will enter ² when you press AltGr + 2 or Left Control + Right Alt + 2, and leave all other Alt + Ctrl + 2 combinations free for use.

Depending on the application, the script above may not work though. E.g., on Google Docs under Chrome, it will always enter ² for any combinations of Alt + Ctrl + 2.

To workaround this, we may use the fact, that AltGr maps to Left Ctrl + Right Alt pressed *simultaneously*. E.g., even w/o AutoHotKey we can enter comment mode on Google Docs with International US keyboard, if we press down Ctrl then press down M then press down Left Alt and then release the keys. But it's not practical to think in what order to press and release the keys. Instead, we may use AutoHotKey for that and change the second line of the script above:

```
<^>!2::SendInput "{Text}²"
^!2::SendInput "{RCtrl down}{2 down}{LAlt down}{2 up}{LAlt up}{RCtrl up}"
```

Sometimes, the problem is the **opposite**: you want to enter some diacritic with AltGr+XXX combination, but that triggers some action bound to Alt+Ctrl+XXX combination. E.g., on **Polish Programmers layout**, if you press AltGr+S to enter Ś diacritic, the Windows Snipping Tool pops up instead on Windows 11. And of you have Evernote installed, then pressing AltGr+N to enter Ń diacritic opens Evernote window to create a new note. This is easily fixable with AutoHotKey. E.g., the problems above need only two corresponding lines:

```
<^>!N::SendInput "{Text}ń"
<^>!S::SendInput "{Text}ś"
```

After that AltGr+N and AltGr+S will correctly enter the corresponding diacritics, while other Ctrl+Alt+N or Ctrl+Alt+S combinations will trigger the appropriate action, like opening the Snipping Tool or New Note window.

Note, that you need to add only those problematic combinations, no need to enter all the existing diacritics.

As a bonus, here is an interesting [history](https://medium.engineering/the-curious-case-of-disappearing-polish-s-fa398313d4df) behind the Poland Programmers layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SharpKeys:

> SharpKeys is a Registry hack that is used to make certain keys on a
>   keyboard act like other keys. For example, if you accidentally hit
>   Caps Lock often, you could use this utility to map Caps Lock to a
>   Shift key or even turn it off completely. This official release
>   includes support for up to 104 mappings, an extensive list of
>   available keys, and a "Type Key" option to help when managing
>   mappings.

I have not used it personally, but know someone who has used it in the past and is quite happy with it.

I am not sure, But maybe switching your keyboard layout to (English UK) might help. Here is a link on [how](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-your-keyboard-layout).

Comment: Took a look at SharpKeys, but it only seems to map one key stroke to another and doesn't do combinations, so it is not helping :(
Switching keyboard layout is not an option, since most symbols are in other locations - even the number of keys are different. But thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this in Windows 10
Settings > Typing > Advanced Keyboard Settings > Override for Default Input Method
Change to a non-international Keyboard (as per your Advanced Keyboard Settings)
Hope that works for others

Answer (score 0):

One good developer BladeMight offered his own workaround for international layouts **(the best and trouble-free in my opinion)** with Mahou app: at the time of typing Ctrl+Alt+ combinations, the keyboard layout will temporarily change to special one where the symbol mode doesn't involve duplicating AltGr to Ctrl+Alt.

Just open Mahou "Layouts" tab and enter in "Temporary change layout on LCtrl+LAlt combination" field: `67699721` (English US code), then click on "Apply" button.

You can freely specify any other (desired) keyboard layout (without AltGr) code for a temporary change (but it makes no difference).

[Download (x64): Direct link](https://gitea.com/BladeMight/Mahou/releases/download/latest-commit/Release_x64.zip)

[Other builds](https://gitea.com/BladeMight/Mahou/releases/tag/latest-commit)

Here are my settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any or only a few of the Alt+Gr keyboard combinations, you can create a custom keyboard layout that removes all the unneeded ones.

For example, these are the only one that I kept in my custom layout:

[image: custom keyboard layout]

I created a repository for myself, but it might be interesting for others as well: https://github.com/fvclaus/windows-us-custom-keyboard-layout

Answer (score -2):

press and hold the NumLock key for 5 seconds.

This worked for me.

I found the answer on the computer here: "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use" ... Mine has a tick next to 'turn on toggle keys by pressing and holding NUMLock for 5 seconds'....

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state. Otherwise, read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.