# Disable CTRL + ALT + [LETTER] to produce accented variations

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

After an unknown config change, `CTRL + ALT + [LETTER]` has started producing common accented versions of `[LETTER]`. I'm not a big fan of this arrangement, seeing as I've memorized all my favourite `ALT + [NUMPAD SEQUENCE]` references and was used to using `CTRL + ALT + [LETTER]` for various other application-specific commands in my text editor.

[The prominent result from my searching](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-you-turn-off-keys-making-special-characters-t3720095.html) suggests that this has something to do with a switch to an 'international keyboard', and says this can be removed in the control panel or toggled by hitting `ALT + SHIFT`, but I can't get my system to confirm this, and the solutions (or close approximations thereof) don't work.

Specifically, I've been to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings` and switched the override for default input method from 'language list' to English and I've been to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Language options` and made sure that I only have my one input method UK — as opposed to international. Other than that I'm not quite sure where to look. Any ideas?

Comment: because [`Ctrl+Alt` acts like `AltGr` on Windows](http://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention if you are on win7 or win8 or xp etc.

If you are on Win8 then go to Control Panel > Language. You will see your current language preference. It also tells you what keyboard layout you are using. If it says international next to keyboard layout. then click options to the right and choose add an input method under Input Method then choose Qwerty US touch keyboard layout.

Comment: Aha. Sorry about that. I'm on Windows 8. I'm not using the international keyboard layout — I'm using UK layout. There are no other keyboard layouts currently selected.

Comment: is this affecting you in all of windows or just in a particular program? if it is in a particular program it may be your settings in that program.

Comment: No, this happens in all contexts (text editor, browser, etc). The symptoms are exactly those of an international keyboard, except that I don't have the international keyboard available — even using the toggle has no effect.

Comment: try adding a different keyboard layout, remove your current layout, then re-add your preferred layout. see if that works. I'm really just guessing here as I have never run into this problem. Maybe try a different keyboard entirely.