# Disable Ctrl+AltGr(!)+Del (but not Ctrl+Alt+Del)

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I’m using Windows 10 and the http://neo-layout.org/ keyboard layout which offers navigational and other keys with the `AltGr` modifier. So `AltGr+C`is `Delete` in my layout.

Now I often want to use `Ctrl+Delete`when programming to delete the next word (or until the next capital letter) to the right and to achieve that I don’t directly press the `Delete`button but the one with `AltGr+C`. So the whole hotkey combination is `Ctrl+AltGr+C` which brings the same dialog as `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` with the option to lock and open the Task Manager etc. I didn’t know before that `Ctrl+AltGr+Delete` also works.

I don’t want to disable `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` interrupt (which I’ve found many answers for) but only the one with `AltGr`. Does anyone have an idea how to realize this?

Comment: [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)