# Windows 10: Right Alt Key working as Clt+Alt Keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, intel-graphics, display-rotation

I have windows 10 on my laptop. The problem comes after Intel graphics diver is installed in the system. When the hot keys given in graphics option is enabled, any of alt+arrow work as <kbd>clt</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd>, i.e.,  as a hot key and rotates my screen even when I am not pressing <kbd>Clt</kbd>. The default <kbd>clt</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> key works as it should be (rotating the screen). But whenever I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd> screen rotates instead of going back or forward or up or skip 10s while watching a video in VLC player.

When I disable hot keys, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd> completely stops working while rest of the shortcut key works. I also tried uninstalling Intel graphics driver but then also it doesn't work and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> keys do nothing while other shortcut key works.

**Edit:** All this is happening only with <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key only. But this does not seem to a hardware problem as I had enabled locate pointer when <kbd>Clt</kbd> is pressed and when I press <kbd>R-Alt</kbd> key alone it doesn't show a circle around the pointer. Also, I tested my <kbd>R-alt</kbd> on Ubuntu 16.04 where it's working completely fine.

Comment: it's the [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) which is different from normal right alt. Change to a different layout that doesn't have AltGr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/592970/can-i-make-ctrlalt-not-act-like-altgr-on-windows)