# Is it possible to type the pound sign (£) on an (American) Kinesis Advantage keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, kinesis-advantage

I'm using the United States International keyboard layout, so pressing `'` and then `o` should make an accented `ó` in Microsoft Windows 10.

The problem is that I'm using a [Kinesis Advantage](https://www.kinesis-ergo.com/products/) keyboard and it doesn't have an <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and it doesn't have a numerical keypad.

Any ideas if there's a way to type the pound sign (£) on this keyboard?

This is the layout:

[image]

Comment: On Windows [`AltGr` is equivalent to `Ctrl+Alt`](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)

Comment: @phuclv - ...as I said in my answer here below...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the US-International keyboard under Windows, if you have two <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, the *right* one gets remapped to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. If you don’t, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> provides the same functionality - that is, to enter ***ß***, you would use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

For the pound-sterling sign ***£***, one would type <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

Comment: I was familiar with AltGr, but I didn't know ctrl+alt = altgr.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I use a customized version of US-INT which allows the ASCII grave, apostrophe, tilde, quote, and caret characters to be typed without annoying dead-key behavior.  Add Alt+GR to those keys to get dead keys.  I have no idea why MS makes keyboard customization such a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Not a Windows person, but knowing that many modern OS’s now accommodate for easier entry of non-common (aka: “International”) characters with (relatively) simple key combinations.

My first suggestion would be to try some of the “usual” alt-character keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) mixed with the <kbd>$</kbd> key and see if that produces a `£` (pound symbol). Like this first try with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>

Or try just the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key like this:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>

Then try adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the combo like this:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>

And finally, try adding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the mix like this:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>