# Using Alt+A clears all text in a textbox

Tags: windows-7, windows, text-editing, alt, greenshot

While entering text into a textbox in Greenshot editor, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> combination (which is needed for the Polish letter "ą"), the whole text entered so far disappears.

I'm using Greenshot on Windows 7 x64.

Here is [the recording of what is happening](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kuuuqqznv0kff0/Alt%2Ba%20problem.mp4?dl=0).

This is the version I'm using: [image: Greenshot 1.2.10 Build 6]

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Hi Przemek, welcome to Superuser! It's good general practice to include your OS version whenever you're having issues with desktop apps. This'll make it easier for users not familiar with Greenshot to help as well. It's assumed you're on **Windows** since that seems to be the only platform this software runs on.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key *on the right* for typing special characters in some languages is called [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) and is **completely different from the normal <kbd>Alt</kbd> key**. In Windows <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is [always mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)

When you press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Windows converts it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. However it seems Greenshot captures the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> before passing the key combination to the keyboard input method which then types `ą`. Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> has selected all texts, the new key will replace everything with ą. I've confirmed that behavior on my PC:

- In the US layout (no AltGr) pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will select all texts just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- In another layout with AltGr but <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> has no special character associated with it pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will insert A

So it's a bug in Greenshot and can't be fixed without modifying Greenshot source code