# Make Right Alt + Shift change languages in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, multilingual

I am - unfortunately - using Windows 10. I need to use two keyboard layouts: English-with-US-Keyboard, and Hebrew-with-Hebrew-Standard-Keyboard. I have them configured, and Left Alt + Shift switches between them. However, Right Alt + Shift (i.e. AltGr+Shift) doesn't. Or more precisely: I'm not even sure it's behaving consistently. Sometimes it just sets Hebrew layout, regardless of the existing active layout; sometimes it seems it seems to not do anything, or just set English.

Anyway - how can I made it behave like LeftAlt+Shift, and switch the layout?

Comment: you can only do that if Right Alt isn't `AltGr` because AltGr is **always** converted to `Ctrl+Alt`. See [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386)

Comment: Haven't you thought about ***direct*** switching to the keyboard you want? In *Language Settings*, set for example US keyboard to Ctrl+Shift+1 and Hebrew keyboard to Ctrl+Shift+0.  That way, you will switch directly to the keyboard you want instead of rotating between them using single combination which does not always work for you and makes you double-check which layout is active.

Answer (score 2):

The right Alt key is probably the AltGr key.
In non-US keyboard layouts, the AltGr key is equivalent to pressing simultaneously
left-Alt and right-Control.

To make the AltGr key equivalent to the left-Alt key, you may use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
with the following script:

```
RAlt::LAlt
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the
Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Answer (score 1):

with [AutoHotKey program](https://www.autohotkey.com/) , This code works for me perfectly .just need to change key sequence settings (on System settings >time and language >language >keyboard >input language hotkeys >advanced key settings) to the below image and make remapped keyboard using the code below: [image: advanced key settings]

```
; "RALt + RShift" to "LAlt + LShift"
>!>+::
 Send {LAlt Down}{LCtrl Down}{LCtrl Up}{LAlt Up}
```

this will set the combination of "Right Alt + Right Shift" keys to work as the Left ones
just put the code in a .ahk file (Thanks to "[harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)" solution) and then follow his rules for putting it as autostart schedule whenever Windows starts...

Comment: Please explain what "AutoHotKey" is.

Answer (score 1):

Put your RTL language at the top of the list. Click "Move UP" to move up.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.