# Ctrl + Alt + L captured by Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

In *IntelliJ IDEA* `Ctrl + Alt + L` is used as a shortcut to trigger reformatting of the source code. Today I discovered that this shortcut does not work anymore. What happens is, that if I hit it twice the Windows session will be locked (just as I would have used `Win + L`.)

Has there been a recent change to the shortcuts in Windows 10? When I try to record this shortcut again in IntelliJ it is not recognized at all.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me. It might be caused by some product that you have installed. To verify, boot in Safe mode and see if this is still happening.

Comment: How do I boot in safe mode?

Comment: Google is your friend : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

Comment: are you using a keyboard layout with AltGr? Because in Windows [Ctrl+Alt is equivalent to AltGr](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386) which means you have to choose a different key combination

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another software registered that key and is capturing it before IntelliJ.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is known to be registered by:

1. Windows 10, [if accessibility is on](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13810/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-accessibility).
2. nVidia GeForce Experience
3. Mouse without Borders

As you explicitly state that your machine locks if you press it twice I would go with `Mouse without Borders` as that shortcut is specifically tied to locking machines.

**Notice the underlined DISABLE, it's a red-herring as you have to click on the actual shortcut and select "disabled" there!**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it was Mouse without Borders :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I been using Mouse Without borders for years and never realized it had shortcuts. Ironically the lock all mashines is the only one that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Another app that captures this shortcut is ASUS Armory Crate: https://old.reddit.com/r/ASUSROG/comments/176c6sf/armoury_crate_resource_monitor/

Comment: Steps to fix issue caused by ASUS Armory Crate: Go to "Device" -> Resource Monitor -> Realtime Monitor (should be ON) -> click "Real-time monitor Settins" -> change the shortcuts (can't be disabled).