# Prevent AltGr from producing upper case letters

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

I have a German keyboard layout, so when I type something like `AltGr` + `ß` I get a `\`. However, when I type e.g. `AltGr` + `g`, I get a `G`. This can be quite annoying, as in LaTeX, this has the effect that I frequently type stuff like `\Gamma`, instead of `\gamma`.

Can the behaviour of `AltGr` be changed, so that it doesn't produce uppercase letters anymore, without disabling the "[third level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)" effect?

I use Windows 10 with the Language "English (Germany) - German".

Comment: Try to use the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to modify the behavior of the keyboard. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/650854/8672) and beware of [this gotcha](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/custom-keyboard-layout-under-windows-10/26f3d73c-b865-42ce-aba3-8004cedbf62e).

Comment: @harrymc this solved the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean [this German keyboard layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdgr)?

Comment: Note that the question this supposedly is a duplicate of didn't answer my question though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by harrymc, using [MSKLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) solves the issue: one can simply set it up in a way, that `AltGr` + a letter, e.g. `g` results in a `g`.